# Where does SNMP OIDs get the data from?

Tags: networking, snmp

If I want to find out network traffic on my Linux Servers using SNMP. I use the ifOutOctets. and ifInOctets. OIDs in an snmpget request. Where do these OIDs get the data from?

Comment: This appears to be a question about network administration and not about Ubuntu. Please ask over on [SF] or [NetworkEngineering.SE].

Comment: @DavidFoerster This would be closed as "Too Broad" there, because I bet that OIDs can come from many different services or methods.  This is also a bit broad because it's really not a specific question and is a very broad question.  (Migration would be declined if it happened, so I'm declining to migrate it for the above reasons)

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu it would seem the ifInOctets. and ifOutOctets. OIDs gather the data from the /proc directory.

This can be verified using `strace -p <pid of SNMP>`. Strace records the system calls of the proccess. Strace produces much output to the terminal when executed, however using the option `-e trace=open` filters the output to what files SNMP is referencing.

Executing the following command `strace -p <pid Of SNMP> -e trace=open` on my Ubuntu device outputs:

```
open("/proc/stat", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 13
open("/proc/vmstat", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 13
open("/proc/net/dev", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 13
open("/proc/net/if_inet6", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 15
open("/proc/sys/net/ipv4/neigh/ppp0/retrans_time_ms", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 15
open("/proc/sys/net/ipv4/neigh/lo/retrans_time_ms", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 15
open("/proc/sys/net/ipv6/neigh/lo/retrans_time_ms", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 15
open("/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/lo/forwarding", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 15
open("/proc/sys/net/ipv6/neigh/lo/base_reachable_time_ms", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 15
open("/proc/sys/net/ipv4/neigh/eth0/retrans_time_ms", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 15
open("/proc/sys/net/ipv6/neigh/eth0/retrans_time_ms", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 15
open("/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/forwarding", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 15
open("/proc/sys/net/ipv6/neigh/eth0/base_reachable_time_ms", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 15
open("/proc/sys/net/ipv4/neigh/eth1/retrans_time_ms", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 15
open("/proc/sys/net/ipv6/neigh/eth1/retrans_time_ms", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 15
open("/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth1/forwarding", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 15
open("/proc/sys/net/ipv6/neigh/eth1/base_reachable_time_ms", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 15
open("/proc/diskstats", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 13
open("/proc/net/dev", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 13
open("/proc/net/if_inet6", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 15
open("/proc/sys/net/ipv4/neigh/ppp0/retrans_time_ms", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 15
```

The file /proc/net/dev contains packet and bytes information on all interfaces. This is the likely data source for ifInOctets and ifOutOctets OIDs on Ubuntu.